# How can I destroy Session by SessionId from different web application in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, webforms

How can I make a button called `Kill Session` on grid view to kill session for users in C#  asp.net web forms?

Comment: In stack you need to provide sample code you tried. Will you please provide the sample code you have been trying?

Comment: we have an httpmodule which we save the sessionid and i have another application which list all the sessions and we need to kill the session based on selection record

Comment: You can't remove session values from a different web application; Session is secure and can be accessed only within that particular browser session;

Answer (score -1):

The naive answer is to have each request check a persistent queue or table of such pending "session kills" before any processing, and conditionally abandon the session.

A quick optimization is to have the application listen globally (i.e. from appstart) and actively to the external queue, so that "kill requests" can be pushed to it immediately. You can then prepare them in a local thread-safe data structure so that normal HTTP requests aren't slowed down.

Your session management application simply sends messages to that queue.

Sidenote: Any "service bus" will do usually. It is rather important than the queue be persistent as you need to handle scenarios revolving around the application restarting while messages are queued up.

The proper answer is to communicate directly with the actual session handler. I don't believe there are any *standard* APIs to do what you want, so this will depend on the session handler (and likely on the host/server).

Comment: This does not actual answer the question.  How does one destroy a session by session ID?

Comment: @SpencerSullivan: As I mentioned you can [Abandon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.abandon.aspx) a session if its [ID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.sessionid.aspx) matches one you have previously put in a "kill queue" while processing a previous request (or in any other context). At the time I seemed to imply there was no standard API to invalidate sessions directly; I could still be wrong.

Comment: Understood.  What we are looking for is actual code that really achieves this magic you suggest.  Not the store IDs in a queue portion.  The actual removal of sessions from a remote process.  I have not seen this done and believe you will get quite the uptick of points if you can demonstrate this.

Comment: @SpencerSullivan: Sure; I linked to the method which I believe you want in my previous comment ([`HttpSessionStateContainer.Abandon`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstatecontainer.abandon.aspx)). It should quickly become clear why I suggested an asynchronous mechanism to invoke it (it can only abandon the current session).

Comment: If you can only abandon the current session, then a queue for abandoning sessions by id (not current) is unrealistic and nullifies your answer.  Asynchronicity does not pertain to the question.  The question is how can one abandon sessions that are not the current session ("users")?

Comment: @SpencerSullivan: Now you understand the problem (there's no generic API for that, apparently). The solution I suggested is to make sure that the next time a user whose session was forcibly canceled by another process ("entered in a kill queue"), the server would immediately abandon the session for real before processing the user request. Same effect. If the user never makes another request, you can clear entries for which you are sure the session is actually expired. If you have direct programmatic access to the actual session handler implementation, you may be able to expire it directly.

Comment: I maintain that you indeed cannot kill a session from a secondary process.  While you speak of this kill queue, it cannot exist IMHO.  If it does, the onus is on you to present one.

Comment: Obviously the queue shall be read from the "primary process" (we should rather say "the context of an active session") for the reason you state, that's its whole reason of being. I'm not sure how to frame this better; (1) enqueue ID of session to kill from "secondary process", (2) whenever you receive a request (in the "primary process"), check the current ID against enqueued IDs, (3) if one matches then call `Abandon` (which you can do since you're in the "primary process"). This is merely a workaround for the lack of an API which could do it directly (i.e. synchronously).